# issue with TeXStudio macro

Tags: texstudio

I have been using TeXStudio since forever and love every bit of it. I am using a few macros that improve my productivity a bit. All of them worked until lately when all of a sudden one stopped working. This is the one that for some reason doesn't work anymore:

```
Name: Subscript

Abbreviation: Sub

Trigger: (?highlighted-as:numbers,math-delimiter,math-keyword)_

Type: Normal

LaTeX Content: _{%|}
```

This is supposed to automatically introduce `_{}` when I press `Shift+-` inside a math environment. I have a similar one for the super script and that works without a problem.

I use TexStudio on both windows 10 and linux manjaro and this macro refuses to trigger on both.

Does anyone have any idea what is happening?

Thank you

Comment: Did you upgrade TeXstudio? Which version are you using?

Comment: on linux i have version 3.1.1 but on windows i have the latest version and in both I encounter this problem. I am not sure at which version it started because I am not writing documents in latex daily.